# how to set paper size to half-letter (5.5 x 8.5 in.) in amsbook?

Tags: formatting

I would like to print a book in a 5.5 x 8.5 format (half of us-letter). How can I set that papersize with the amsbook document class? Is there some alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `geometry`:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\geometry{
  paperheight=8.5in,
  paperwidth=5.5in,
  heightrounded,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\kant

\end{document}
```

You may want to set other `geometry` options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `geometry` package. Also I assume you want 8.5 x 5.5 because a US letter is 8.5 x 11. However, if this is not the case it is simple to change.

Code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperheight=5.5in,paperwidth=8.5in,margin=2in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]